# Overwrite Sentinel's RepositoryTrait

Tags: php, database, model, traits, sentinel

In order to use a second database with Sentinel, all models must have a "connection" property with the desired name of the database or they will just use the default database (because it's built with Eloquent ORM).

Currently, Sentinel doesn't offer that option. Anyway, I figured out how to make it work: In cartalyst/support/src/Traits/RepositoryTrait.php I edited the createModel method:

```
public function createModel(array $data = [])
{
    $class = '\\'.ltrim($this->model, '\\');

    $class = new $class($data);

    return $class;
}
```

I added the following line of code before the return line:

```
$class->setConnection('second_database_name');
```

Now, I want to make this change permanent so I won't have to change the code again in the next update of Sentinel, and also I want to "composer install" Sentinel as usual so I need the change to be in a different folder.

What's the best way for me to do that?

Comment: You could just fork it and keep your fork up to date with the origin. You could also stay with the original source and write a tiny script that'll apply your *patch* after each update. There are many ways. The answer is yes. Try avoiding plain yes/no questions as they tend to be less *"good"*.

Comment: @m02ph3u5 I'm thinking maybe there is even a better way to do it, since in the trait there is a __call method to "Dynamically pass missing methods to the model" and a setMethod - "Runtime override of the model". Maybe I could re-configure the models from my own file. Any idea?

Comment: This is the trait file: http://paste.ofcode.org/QSqYjyUPgBGEtQfbbzU4Cc